# ERROR: Execution of script failed! $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I've used my script on Tampermonkey (Firefox) for 6 month.
At now I have this error, script work partially, not all time.
I don't know why.

I have tries various suggestions about jQuery, doesn't work

Top of my script:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
function RPP(){
    RedeemRPProduct('fp_bonus_100');
}

var body = $('body'); //I think error is here..

var points = {};
```

At now script works some times. When it doesn't works appear in console this error: 
ERROR: Execution of script 'script-name' failed! $ is not defined

What's happened?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you never defined `$`. Either require jQuery, or ditch it and use built-in DOM methods instead

Comment: Your script probably has `@grant none` and you've been using site's jQuery, not your own. Then the site changed something and you've started to experience problems. Edit your question and show your userscript's header (the first big comment block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause is that the website administrators removed `jQuery` from their code. With modern JS, it's mostly obsolete for things like selectors. I recommend simply removing jQuery references from your script and use normal DOM API:

To access body:

```
document.body
```

To find an element using selector:

```
document.querySelector("div#my_div")
```

Alternatively you could include jQuery in your script using `@require`.

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem is solved, but leaving this here for others with the same error...

I'm also using Firefox, and my Tampermonkey was 1 year old (I forgot that I disabled the addon's auto updating). It worked fine, I never had the problem you described. Till a couple of days ago when I updated to the new version, and my userscripts stopped loading 10% of the times (got the mentioned error message in console).

Newer Tampermonkey-s are much faster than older versions, loading the userscripts earlier, sometimes before the jQuery library script of the original site is loaded, even if you are using `// @run-at document-end`.

How I fixed: wrapped my whole userscript content into 1 function, which is called only when the jQuery script is 100% loaded, using a checker function.

Add the next line to the top of your script, right after the Header:

```
function runScript() {
```

Add the next lines to the bottom of your script (to the end):

```
};

var waitForJQuery = setInterval(function () {
    if (typeof $ != 'undefined') {
        $(runScript);
        clearInterval(waitForJQuery);
    }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're referencing jQuery (via the `$`) before it has loaded into the page.
It is working sometimes as I'm guessing on some occasions jQuery manages to load before you make your call...but sometimes it doesn't and you see the error.

Try this:

```
<script src="...your jquery reference..."/> <!-- at the top of your page -->

<!-- at the bottom of the page -->
<script>
var body;
var points = {};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    body = $(body); //it won't try and use jQuery until the doc is ready

    //...other script stuff...
});

</script>
```

Comment: The OP has a userscript so the page is a third-party.